# Brownian motion distribution and probability space

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

We know that $B_t \sim N(0,t)$ has the same distribution of $\sqrt tB_1 \sim \sqrt tN(0,1)=N(0,t)$

1) why it is wrong do the following: $E[B_tB_s] = \sqrt t \sqrt sE[B_1B_1]$. Instead it hold that $E[B_t-B_s]=E[\sqrt tB_1-\sqrt sB_1]$ , but I guess it is only a coincidence here.

2) often we sum and subtract a brownian motion for bringing us back to an increment and exploiting the independence. Summing and subtracting a r.v.s does not change the result, indeed $+B_s-B_s=0$. However this result hold because we pick up this two Brownian motion from the same probability space. If they come from a different space the result does not hold. Until here it is right? (please give a feedback also on this)

But what does it mean taking two Brownian motion from a different probability space? The answer should be that for a different $\omega$, for a fixed $t$, the r.v. $B_t$ assume a different value w.r.t. another Brownian motion, say $W_t$.
Could someone provide a more concrete example of two probability spaces where I can define two Brownian motion?

Comment: $B_tB_s\overset{d}{\ne}\sqrt{ts}B_1^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brownian Motion has only independent increases ( that is $B_{t_1} , B_{t_2} - B_{ t_1} , ... B_{t_k} -B_{t_{k-1}} $ are independent for $0\le t_1 < t_2 < ... <t_k$. So writing $B_t = \sqrt tB_1$ isn't the best choice, because then $B_{t_1} = \sqrt t_1B_1 $ and $B_{t_2} - B_{t_1} = (\sqrt{t_2} - \sqrt{t_1})B_1 $ are clearly dependent.

So you can $\mathbb E[B_t - B_s] = \mathbb E[B_t] - \mathbb E[B_s] = 0-0 = 0$, since $B_x \sim \mathcal N(0,x)$

But assuming $t\ge s$ , $\mathbb E[B_sB_t] = \mathbb E[B_sB_t - B_sB_s +B_sB_s] = \mathbb E[B_s^2] + \mathbb E[B_s(B_t-B_s)]$. The first one is just the second moment of $\mathcal N(0,s)$, and the second, due to independence and symetry of $\mathcal N(0,s)$ is $0$. When you wanted to plug $B_t = \sqrt{t}B_1, B_s = \sqrt{s}B_1$ you will lose your independence of increments, so it isn't good.

As for the last question, you know, there are many different random variables having the same distribution. Say you have Brownian Motion on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$, that is $B:\Omega \to C[0,1]$, $B = (B_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ where you have a set $A \in \mathcal F$ such that $\mathbb P(A) = 0$. Then you can do the following: Define $W:\Omega \to C[0,1]$, $W = (W_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ such that $W(\omega) = B(\omega)$ for every $\omega \in \Omega , \omega \notin A$ and $W(\omega) = c_\omega$ for $\omega \in A$  $($By $c_\omega$ I mean the $c_\omega-$ constant function (dependent of $\omega$) $c_\omega(t) = c_\omega$, for any $t \in [0,1])$

Then clearly both $W,B$ have the same distribution, since for any $E \in \mathcal B(C[0,1])$ (borel set), since we have $(\mu_W -$distribution of $W$ , $ \mu_B -$ distribution of $B)$

$\mu_{W}(E) = \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : W(\omega) \in E \} = \mathbb P( \{ \omega \in \Omega : W(\omega) \in E, W(\omega) \notin A \}) = \mathbb P(\{\omega \in \Omega: B(\omega) \in E, B(\omega) \notin A \}) = \mathbb P(\{ \omega \in \Omega: B(\omega) \in E\} = \mu_B(E)$

But when we take $c_\omega \neq B(\omega)(0)$ (value of $B(\omega)$ at $t=0$ (cause $B$ is random variable to set $C[0,1]$, then for any $\omega \in A$ we have $W(\omega) \neq B(\omega)$, so they are different, but still both has the same distribution of BrownianMotion.

If you want different probability spaces, note that you can just define $W_A : \Omega_A \to C[0,1]$, where $\Omega_A = \{ \omega \in \Omega : \omega \notin A \}$ and $W_A(\omega) = W(\omega)$ for any $\omega \in \Omega_A$

Note I gave you example of both: first -(the same probability space, different R.V, but still both brownian motion) and the second (different probability space, still brownian motion).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Therefore which are the conditions that allow me to cancel out two random variables when I subtract them? namely $B_s-B_s=0$ (now we could also speak more in general of r.v. and not Brownian motion defined on the same time point.)

Comment: Random Variables are functions, so to have $X- Y = 0$, you must have $X(\omega) - Y(\omega) = 0$. Note that when you trying to add/substract something, it is only YOUR CHOICE what to add/substract. You can always add/substract r.v living on the same probability space. But in the case of Brownian motion, most of add/substract stuff is made when dealing with Expected Values/ Variations /etc. that is: things that are dependent only on the distribution of your random variables, so you don't really need to bother whether adding/substracting r.v which lives on the same probability space, but you can

Comment: As you said to have X-Y=0 you must have X($\omega$)-Y($\omega$)=0 for every $\omega$. This imply that the distribution have to be the same and also that the random variable take the same value for each $\omega$. Therefore, the requisite should be two: same probability space, and same function for each $\omega$. Right?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I meant when talking about $X(\omega) - Y(\omega)$

Comment: ok great. Last question: why it is wrong the following: $E[e^{t^{-1/2}B_t - s^{-1/2}B_s}]=E[e^{B_1 - B_1}]=E[1]=1$. Very grateful for your answer

Comment: As I said, it is not true that $B_s = \sqrt{s}B_1$. Those have the same distribution, but aren't equal, simply because then we would have $B_{t} - B_s = \sqrt{t-s}B_1 = \frac{\sqrt{t-s}}{\sqrt{s}}B_s$, but as we know, Brownian Motion has independent increments. It is a difference between being equal to and having the same distribution (my whole answer above is about it)

Comment: I see that having the same distribution is different from being equal, but then I don't see the difference between E[$B_t$]= E[$\sqrt t B_1$] and $E[e^{B_t}] = E[e^{\sqrt t B_1}]$ and we know the first to be true.

Comment: There is no difference between $\mathbb E[B_t] = \mathbb E[\sqrt{t}B_1]$, since $B_t \sim \sqrt{t}B_1$, and $\mathbb E[]$ depends only on distribution. Same with $\mathbb E[e^{B_t}]$... but when it comes to Expected Value of function of $2$ or more random variables, their joint distribution goes in the way, that is $(B_s,B_t)$ isn't distributed as $(\sqrt{s}B_1, \sqrt{t}B_1)$ as I was trying to point out whole time why (increments are independent)

Comment: how do you see that $B_{t_2} - B_{t_1} = (\sqrt{t_2} - \sqrt{t_1})B_1 $ are dependent? Because if it is simply for the relation of $t_1$ and $t_2$ then is seems to me that also $B_{t_2}-B_{t_1}$ is not independent to $B_{t_1}-B_{t_0}$ since they both share $t_1$

Comment: no no no, I said when it would be true that $B_t = \sqrt{t}B_1$ (which isn't true as I was trying to convince you about), then $B_t - B_s = (\sqrt{t} - \sqrt{s})B_1$ would be dependent of $B_s = B_s - B_0 = \sqrt{s}B_1$ and as we know, increments are independent, so they cannot be dependent